# How to fix MongoDB array concatination error?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, concatenation, pentaho-spoon

I have a collection in mongodb with a few million documents. there is an attribute(categories) that is an array that contains all the categories that a document belongs to. I am using following query to convert the array into a comma separated string to add it to SQL server through a spoon transformation.
for example
the document has ["a","b","c",...] and i need a,b,c,.... so i can pit it in a column

```
categories: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: [{ $type: "$categories" }, "array"] },
          {
            $trim: {
              input: {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$categories",
                  initialValue: "",
                  in: { $concat: ["$$value", ",", "$$this"] }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "$categories"
        ]
      }
```

when i run the query i get the following error and i cannot figure out what the problem is.

```
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 16702 and error message '$concat only supports strings, not array' on server
```

a few documents had this attribute as string and not array so i added a type check. but still the issue is there. any help on how to narrow down the issue will be very appreciated.

A few other attributes were the same in the same collection and this query is working fine for the rest of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem in your aggregation. It shouldn't give this error. Can you try to update your `mongodb` version?

However, your aggregation is not working properly `reduce` wasn't working . I converted it to this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            categories: {
                $cond: [
                    {
                        $eq: [{ $type: "$categories" }, "array"]
                    },
                    {
                        '$reduce': {
                            'input': '$categories',
                            'initialValue': '',
                            'in': {
                                '$concat': [
                                    '$$value',
                                    { '$cond': [{ '$eq': ['$$value', ''] }, '', ', '] },
                                    '$$this'
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "$categories"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Edit:

So, if you have nested arrays in the `categories` field. We can flat our arrays with `unwind` stage. So if you can add these 3 stages above the `$project` stage. Our aggregation will work.

```
  {
    "$unwind": "$categories"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$categories"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: null,
      categories: {
        $push: "$categories"
      }
    }
  },
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YsAGStkcy63)

Comment: getting the same error, is there a way to see which exact row is causing the issue??

Comment: Ok, so the issue is that there is a array in one of the elements of an array. like [1,[2,3]]. how do i process this

Comment: @ghengalala I edited my answer. Let me know if have any other question